# ffmpeg and php does not end the conversion

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I'm going crazy with it and do not think the solution.

I use this code to convert videos, but the conversion did not terminate. I tried several times and stops at different points.

```php
echo "Starting ffmpeg...\n\n".'</br>';
echo shell_exec('/usr/src/ffmpeg/ffmpeg/ffmpeg -y -i movie.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex "overlay=10:10" -b:v 1500k -vcodec libx264 movie2.mp4 2> out.txt').'</br>';  
echo "Done.\n";
```

Output from `ffmpeg`:

```
ffmpeg version git-2014-01-31-dce9321 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jan 31 2014 20:37:02 with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/ffmpeg --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/ffmpeg/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/ffmpeg/lib --bindir=/usr/local/ffmpeg/bin --extra-libs=-ldl --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libfdk_aac --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libfreetype --enable-libtheora
  libavutil      52. 63.100 / 52. 63.100
  libavcodec     55. 49.101 / 55. 49.101
  libavformat    55. 28.101 / 55. 28.101
  libavdevice    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
  libavfilter     4.  1.101 /  4.  1.101
  libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101
  libswresample   0. 17.104 /  0. 17.104
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'movie.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    creation_time   : 2016-06-09 07:48:54
  Duration: 00:21:20.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 293 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 164 kb/s, -7.31 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-06-09 07:48:54
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 125 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-06-09 07:27:52
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #1, image2, from 'logo.png':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #1:0: Video: png, rgba, 350x32 [SAR 3779:3779 DAR 175:16], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
[libx264 @ 0x3b1fe00] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x3b1fe00] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA3 LZCNT BMI2
[libx264 @ 0x3b1fe00] profile High, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 0x3b1fe00] 264 - core 142 r2 956c8d8 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2014 - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=24 lookahead_threads=4 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=abr mbtree=1 bitrate=1500 ratetol=1.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'movie2.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf55.28.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 1500 kb/s, 30k tbn, 29.97 tbc (default)
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (libfaac) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-06-09 07:27:52
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> overlay:main (graph 0)
  Stream #1:0 (png) -> overlay:overlay (graph 0)
  overlay (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac -> libfaac)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=   14 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=   15226kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A   
[libfaac @ 0x3b20800] Queue input is backward in time
[mp4 @ 0x3b1ef80] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 3003, current: 1024; changing to 3004. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x3b1ef80] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 3004, current: 2048; changing to 3005. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
frame=   25 fps=6.9 q=0.0 size=   15382kB time=00:00:00.23 bitrate=542687.8kbits/s   
frame=   46 fps= 10 q=0.0 size=   15408kB time=00:00:00.95 bitrate=132582.7kbits/s   
frame=   69 fps= 13 q=32.0 size=   15433kB time=00:00:01.71 bitrate=73576.8kbits/s   
[...] 
frame=11100 fps= 38 q=0.0 size=   24980kB time=00:06:09.77 bitrate= 553.4kbits/s   
frame=11106 fps= 38 q=0.0 size=   25093kB time=00:06:09.98 bitrate= 555.6kbits/s   
frame=11131 fps= 38 q=0.0 size=   25109kB time=00:06:10.82 bitrate= 554.7kbits/s
```

With small video works, but with great video does not end. I do not think it's `php.ini` configuration because there is no error. Just do not end

Comment: If you run the `ffmpeg` command manually, unscripted in a command line interface does it work as expected? Your `ffmpeg` is old and unsupported.